# Creating a "Unsafe" File Format - OK on Local File System, but Prompt from Browser

Tags: windows, security, internet-explorer, firefox, registry

What is the correct way to create a file extension (and maybe a MIME type) that will run from your local file system without prompt, but if you browsed to that file through Internet Explorer or Firefox you would get prompted (warned)? What is the exact mechanism in the windows registry that controls this?

Comment: a document format? because you just describe an exe.

Comment: Yes. A document format like .hta or .bat. What about the way these are set up in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT makes them safe?

Comment: @Tyndall I dont think either of those formats are safe!

Comment: Good point. I should have reverse my language in the question. I'll fix that now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This mechanism is not controlled by the registry.
What IE does is add a NTFS stream to downloaded files, specifcying which zone it was downloaded from.

For example, I just downloaded notepad++, and performed the following command to show the alternate stream:

`c:\Downloads>more <npp.5.4.5.installer.exe:Zone.Identifier`

Which outputted:

```
  [ZoneTransfer]
  ZoneId=3
```

Windows explorer / ShellExecute uses this alternate stream as a means to trigger the "unsafe" warning.

Comment: Just did some testing. IE seems to handle this the way I would expect. Firefox makes you download the file (then open) with prompt - and disables the checkbox option to make the prompt go away. interesting. +1 thanks for the insight

Answer (score 3):

Check IZoneIdentifier and IAttachmentExecute on MSDN for info about the documented way to handle this stuff without messing with NTFS alternative data streams

Comment: +1 Good to know this stuff is available. How would I manipulate these without a browser plug-in or my own app?